# How does this ? operator work in regex?

Tags: regex

`^.*(?=.*[0-9]).*$`

I saw this posted in someone's code.  Is this a valid regex? I know the `?` is supposed to make the items before it optional like `abc?` makes `c` optional.  But `?` is at the start of a capturing bracket.  What does that mean?

Comment: I find the documentation for PCRE on php.net (http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) to be a decent reference on teaching the many features available with regular expressions.  It covers lookaheads, lookbehinds, etc...  The `?` in regular expressions has many different uses!

Comment: Oh I see, are these PHP specific? Or general regex syntax?

Comment: They're general.  Certain implementations of regular expressions may not support all features, but the syntax is quite standard.  The main difference is whether POSIX or PCRE regular expressions are implemented.  POSIX is usually found in *nix command line/shell systems mostly, whereas PCRE is what came from Perl and is more feature-full and used more often.

Comment: Hmm I'm still trying to understand how this operator works exactly.  I have sample string `abc=dfg9abc` and it works with regex `.*(.*[0-9]).*` or `.*(=.*[0-9]).*` but how can I modify the string to work with `.*(?=.*[0-9]).*`?

Comment: @Jonas It sure works with that too (without any modification). Have a look : http://regexr.com?30m54

Comment: It's difficult to help you if I don't know what you're trying to do with the expression - are you looking to just get a true/false match, or are you trying to parse the text and split it up in to groups?

Comment: Basically your regexes mean : 1) anything - then anything or number - then anything. 2) anything - then anything or number or the equal sign - then anything. 3) anything - only if (anything or number) follows - then followed by anything. They all sound pretty much the same to me, huh?

Comment: Well I don't have anything particular to use with this regex.  I just saw it and it confused me so I'm trying to figure out what it does.  I was testing in Notepad++... doesn't seem to support `?=`

Comment: FYI, that regex is incorrect: it should be `^(?=.*[0-9]).*$`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`?` alone means : OPTIONALLY match what was before.

However, `(? .. )` is used for assertions...

In your case, `(?=` is a look-ahead assertion, meaning : match if ONLY (what's in the brackets) follows.

> ### Reference
>
> ---
>
> **(?: ... )**
>
> Non-capturing parentheses. Groups the included pattern, but
>   does not provide capturing of matching text. Somewhat more efficient
>   than capturing parentheses.
>
> **(?> ... )**
>
> Atomic-match parentheses. First match of the parenthesized
>   subexpression is the only one tried; if it does not lead to an overall
>   pattern match, back up the search for a match to a position before the
>   "(?>"
>
> **(?# ... )**
>
> Free-format comment (?# comment ).
>
> **(?= ... )**
>
> Look-ahead assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern
>   matches at the current input position, but does not advance the input
>   position.
>
> **(?! ... )**
>
> Negative look-ahead assertion. True if the parenthesized
>   pattern does not match at the current input position. Does not advance
>   the input position.
>
> **(?<= ... )**
>
> Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized pattern
>   matches text preceding the current input position, with the last
>   character of the match being the input character just before the
>   current position. Does not alter the input position. The length of
>   possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be
>   unbounded (no * or + operators.)
>
> **(?<! ... )**
>
> Negative Look-behind assertion. True if the parenthesized
>   pattern does not match text preceding the current input position, with
>   the last character of the match being the input character just before
>   the current position. Does not alter the input position. The length of
>   possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be
>   unbounded (no * or + operators.)

Comment: So you mean `?=` together is a operator? I thought it was searching for a `=` equals.  Can you give an exmaple of how `(.*[0-9])` would be different?

Comment: @EliSand Well, this one is quite a good resource as well... Good to have pointed that out! ;-)

Comment: @Jonas in this very particular example, I doubt it could make ANY difference. But I'll give you an example : check out this (http://regexr.com?30m4u) (without look-ahead assertion) and this (http://regexr.com?30m51)... And you'll see the difference... ;-)

Comment: Sorry, moved my comment to poster since it made more sense there than here.  Aside from assertions though, the neatest thing I like about `?` is being able to do something like `.*?` to toggle greediness.

Comment: @Jonas And, yep, it's NOT looking for `=` signs. It WOULD if it was like `=?`. So, it IS an operator.

Comment: @EliSand Truth is, although I initially hated it, I DO LOVE RegEx altogether; and don't ask me why... lol ;-)

Comment: @Jonas - an assertion basically makes sure that what you're looking for exists (ahead or behind), but it doesn't "consume" the match, meaning that when the regex parser moves to the next part of the pattern, it continues searching from where it was right when it hit the assertion.  When you get the hang of it, assertions are **very** powerful.

Comment: Dr.Kameleon, I looked at your regex here http://regexr.com/?30m51 which has `foo\s?(?=foo)`.  I added a few extra `foo` to search for (and removed a few `foo`) and to me it just seems to highlight everything except the last foo? I'm not quite sure what the purpose of this operator is.

Comment: @DrK: By "(?<something) is used for assertions" doesn't make sense.  What you're got there is either a malformed lookbehind - `(?<=…)`, `(?<!…)` - or a malformed named group - `(?<name>…)` - (which is not an assertion).

Comment: @AlanMoore I was just trying to imply `(? ..)` where `..` stands for `<something>`. Obviously, it wasn't that self-explanatory. My bad. I'm fixing it...

Comment: Okay, but "assertions" isn't the right word; that only applies to the lookarounds.  Say rather that any group that starts with `(?` is *non-capturing* (except named groups, of course).

Comment: When would someone use a positive look-ahead assertion? I've used the negative look-ahead to exclude somethings.

Comment: @Jonas Yep, that's what it does. Basically, we tell it to match all "foo"s as long as they are followed by (the look-ahead assertion) a... "foo". So, guess what : in our example, yes, it matches everything but the last "foo" ('coz it simply isn't followed by a foo). By using NEGATIVE look-ahead assertion (which is more commonly used), you could also get just that... the last "foo". (by using `foo(?!foo)` = match a "foo" NOT followed by a "foo")

Comment: I saw that example and I know what it's doing but I don't know in what situation you would want to do something like that?